# Confusion about sed and '>'

Tags: bash, sed, pipe

The following command works fine:

```
sed s/input/raw_input/ p.py >p2.py && mv p2.py p.py
```

However, the following command turns p.py into an empty file:

```
sed s/input/raw_input/ p.py >p.py
```

The following also turns p.py into an empty file:

```
sed s/input/raw_input/ p.py | cat > p.py
```

Why don't the last two commands behave as expected? In particular why is p.py empty?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because the redirection operator `>` is called before any command and thus the following happens in this order:

1. `p.py` is opened for writing, truncating whatever was there before
2. `sed` is called to perform commands on `p.py` which is now empty
3. The output (which is nothing) is written to `p.py` (so it still contains nothing)

You have two options depending on how portable you want your code to be:

**not portable**

Use GNU `sed -i` option to do an in-place edit

**portable**

redirect the output to a temp file then move the temp file over the original after `sed` is complete

Comment: Is the order of steps 1 and 2 is well defined; in other words, can you actually count on it emptying the file before `sed` opens it?  (Of course if you simply avoid writing such ugly commands it doesn't matter.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, this is well defined by the shell.  Not sure what you mean by *ugly commands* though, redirecting to a file is a common, and non-ugly, thing to do.

Comment: A third option, if you'd rather not have to deal with making temp files, is to use `ed` instead.

Comment: I'd call redirecting to a file that you're reading ugly (no offense to the OP intended).

Comment: @KeithThompson ahh, yes. In that case I would call it *broken* more than anything ;)

Comment: there is also sponge from [moreutils](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/)